# Resizing UIView with UIScrollView subview

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a big problem concerning the resizing of a derived `UIView` with a `UIScrollView` as subview.

In the `layoutSubviews` message I set the frame of the UIScrollView subview. the `UIScrollView` contains a `UIImageView` with a big image which can be moved/pinched and so on. The initial `contenSize` of the `UIScrollView` is the initial image size.

So far, so good. Moving and pinching of the image works well. Now I have to change the UIView frame (in my app to maximize the UIView). im doing that in a animation block (`beginAnimations`/`commitAnimations`). So I set the new frame (which will update the width & height) an then I call `[myView layoutIfNeeded]` to force the UIScrollView to update its frame in the `layoutSubviews` message of my view.

The `UIView` animates correct to its new frame and if the `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` is currently `x 0, y 0` the `UIScrollView` frame will be updated properly. but here's my problem: if the `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` is **bigger than** `x 0, y 0` the `UIScrollView` will "slide in" from upper left to its final position.

I want that the UIScrollView resizes its frame properly with the parents frame and aligns the content (in my case the `UIImageView`) right. But how could I achieve that?

Comment: You can link your accounts, here is how: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after hours of web research i found the solution for this problem:

```
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
```

this will animate all layers from the current state.

Comment: You can mark this as the answer (even though it's your own), which will show that the question is resolved.